# Get access to {{> atForm}} Template in Meteor 1.4

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, user-accounts, meteor-accounts

Im trying to import the `useraccounts:unstyled` package into my code. What do I have to `import` in order to have access to the `{{> atForm}}` template. It's Meteor 1.4.

I'm still very new to Meteor, so I appreciate every answer.

This is my template code:

```
<template name="LoginModal">
  <div class="login-modal">
    <i class=fa fa-close close-login></i>
    {{> atForm}}
  </div>
</template>
```

I'm getting a bunch of this warnings in the browser console:

> Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of undefined
>       at AT.getState (http://localhost:3000...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem. As I said, I'm very new to Meteor - so it was a simple thing. Instead of the `accounts-base` package, I had the `accounts-ui` package installed.

So, if you have the same error, execute:

`meteor add accounts-base`

in your console.